# Sync latest email attachment with Android

Tags: email, sync

My college mess hall menu is shared as an attachment (.jpeg) on the **same thread** every week. The thread has no other content except for this.
For convenience, I'd like to access it quickly from my Android mobile. I don't want to keep it as a starred conversation and interrupt my urgent emails.

Is there a way to sync the file (i.e the latest attachment on the thread) so that I can have one click access to it? Maybe sync it to google drive so I can use widget or rename it to current_mess_menu.jpg and save it in a Dropbox folder so I can do the same? Open to other alternatives as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use the Gmail app, it always downloads the attachment if you're on WiFi AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the app 'If This Then That' (IFTTT) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ifttt.ifttt

Comment: You should expand your answer and explain how this app will accomplish the task that the user is asking.